# JS get element position after animation interrupt

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have an element, which I move across the screen using an animation:

```
slide.animate({'left': value*100 + '%'}, transitiontime * 1000)
```

When a specific event occurs, I stop the animation using

```
slide.stop();
```

now I want to get the current 'left' value using

```
slide.css('left');
```

but unfortunately I get a 'px' value instead of percent, which I used in the animation.
Is there a way to get the percent value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens because `css()` actually uses javascript's `getcomputedstyle()` function and it always returns in pixels.

you can achieve what you want like this:

```
var left=(100 / $(window).width()) * parseInt(slide.css('left').split('px')[0]) + '%';
```

the above code returns a value in percentage **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kzv7puvc/)**

Comment: This did the trick. Thank You very much!